# Homepage elements are faded out and don't work

Tags: html, css

Hopefully, one of you vets can help me out here.  If you look at my homepage, [here](http://www.realtimehockey.net/), you will see that I have a main accordion slider with three separate slideshows directly below that with ads being the components of the slideshow.  Upon page load, these slideshow ads become darkened or "faded out" and the slideshow never starts.  In hovering over the ads, a tool tip pops up saying "Adobe Flash Player".  No idea where this is coming from but, if you click one of the ads, the ad "brightens" and the slideshow begins.  I used Zoho to create site and I know in the past there have been conflicts with their built-in CSS but, I can't seem to figure out where that conflict might be.  Furthermore, and I assume the issues is causing this as well, my background image is not appearing.  Just a dull gray.  If you check a sub-page, [here](http://www.realtimehockey.net/tournaments.html), you will see the background image appears as it should.  I'm not exactly sure where to even begin to figure this out.  I thought maybe the main accordion slider was affecting things but, I removed that and still got the same result.  I apologize in advance for the possible bad terminology but I'm new to this and could use all the help I can get.  I'd appreciate any assistance you might be able to give me.  Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Please add meaningful code to your question. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: If you right click the ad, you can see it asks if you want to "run this plugin". I assume you're using Chrome, but it's probably a security/usability measure to ensure flash scripts are only ran when the user wants them to be

Comment: Using Adobe Flash is quite outdated on the web and there are alternatives to achieve the same effects

Comment: I apologize for not posting the code, however, in using Zoho there are too many characters and it won't all fit.  @Joseph Young I am using Chrome.  This wasn't created as a flash slide show so, I'm not even sure where that is coming from.  I've had these same slideshows on the site for quite sometime and never had this issue until I added the accordion slider.

Comment: @j08691 I appreciate the info, however, I'm still not sure where in the code the issue is or would be and there is too much to post it all.  The area where I am having the problem is coded with simple iframes so, that won't tell much of a story.  I will do what I can to try and narrow down the possibilities and post that code.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Remove `background: #ccc;` on line `295` on your `index.html` file. It should sort out your background issue. It would also be a good idea to put all your styling in one place.

The carousel works fine for me. 
The tool tip is probably adware. You may want to scan for unwanted extensions.
This should be of help. http://bit.ly/1vtTBg7

Comment: thanks so much.  I had to step out but, I will try both when I get back.  Adware would make sense because all this transpired with very few changes.  In using Zoho they automatically throw a bunch of extra styling in the code, which makes for quite a mess, when trying to figure out an issue.  I do appreciate your help and will update shortly.

Comment: again, thanks for your assistance.  The background issue resolved perfectly with your advice.  The ad issue did not.  As far as I can tell, this may just be a Chrome issue as I did try it on IE and it worked fine.  I'm not sure if there is something I can ad to code to amend this or not.  Any thoughts?  Again, thanks for your time and assistance.

Comment: No worries. Did you try reinstalling chrome?